# How can I get a list of all files *I* have committed to Git (GitHub repo) after a certain date?

Tags: git, github

The list should include creation, modifications, and deleted files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can come up with for your question is something like

```
git log --no-merges --stat --author="name" --pretty=format:"%C(Yellow)%h%Creset - %ad%n"
```

which will show the file revision history by a specific user, but grouped by commits.

If you want to see a simple name-only list, I suggest using h0tw1r3's answer from this related question: [Can I get git to tell me all the files one user has modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349139/can-i-get-git-to-tell-me-all-the-files-one-user-has-modified)

```
git log --no-merges --stat --author="Pattern" --name-only --pretty=format:"" | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Point #1 - you don't commit files in `git`. You create a commit, which is a snapshot of your entire project.

Point #2 - try `git help log` - look for especially the `--author=...`, `--committer=...`, `--before=...`, and `--after=...` options.

Comment: Also the `--stat` and `--numstat` options.