# Finding all files touched by a particular author in git history?

Tags: git

Is there a way I can use standard git commands to find all the files that were touched by a particular author in a git repository, ideally between two specified dates? I know I can use `git log --author="Name"`, but ideally I'd just like a list of filenames, and nothing else.

Comment: This may help you https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html

Comment: If git had `git blame <directory>`, it would be as simple as grepping output, but it doesn't...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See this answer [Can I get git to tell me all the files one user has modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349139/can-i-get-git-to-tell-me-all-the-files-one-user-has-modified)

```
git log --pretty="%H" --author="authorname" | while read commit_hash; do git show --oneline --name-only $commit_hash | tail -n+2; done | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It works beautifully.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally to Manuel van Rijn's answer for find logs only between two specified dates

```
git log [<options>] [<since>..<until>] [[--] <path>…]
```

**SOURCE:** https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html