# Get list of commits where a specific user has modified a specific file

Tags: git

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349139/can-i-get-git-to-tell-me-all-the-files-one-user-has-modified), but it doesn't really address what I need. I know what file I'm interested in; I need to get a list of commits where I've modified that particular file. Is this possible? I work on a team of 6 devs, so there are literally thousands of commits in our repo.

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I view a git log of just one user's commits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits)

Comment: Not really; my question specifically required the file name to be included as an option, which the question your referring to did not answer.

Comment: I don't consider that to be a significant difference, especially when [the documentation states that you can restrict the log to an individual path](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html), but if other people disagree, they can simply vote to reopen the question if it's closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually really simple, just combine `--author` with the path of the file that you are interested in.

```
git log --author="My Name" -- <this_file>
```