# Git list all files which I edited from beginning of the project

Tags: git, list, file, show

I worked in a project for more than 4 months and used GIT for repo. 4 members in the team has feature branches and they do PR from other branches. What I want is list of CSS files(with full path) which I worked in the branch or project from beginning of the time (i.e 4 months ago).

I tried `git diff --name-only <beginnig-of-branch-name>` but it does not work. Please help.

Comment: Can you please show an example of the output you're trying to get and explain why the command you've shared gives insufficient output?

Comment: @Mureinik Example, scenario 1:I edit the file src/namespace/my_bundle/resources/css/styles.css on Sep'2015 in a feature branch and it is merged to master.
scenario 2:I edit the file src/other_namespace/my_bundle/resources/css/styles.css on Oct'2015 in a feature branch and it is merged to master.
Like wise I worked in CSS file for more than 4 months and all are merged to master. But now I need the list of CSS files which I worked under the repository. From above scenario, list of files are.
-src/namespace/my_bundle/resources/css/styles.css
-src/other_namespace/my_bundle/resources/css/styles.css

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to [filter the log by author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6349483/6309):

```
git log --no-merges --stat --author="Pattern" --name-only --pretty=format:"" '*.css'
```

(on Windows, use double quotes for the file extension filter: `"*.css"`)

Replace "`Pattern`" by your author name.

Example:

```
vonc@voncp C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\git
> git log --no-merges --stat --author="Junio.*" --name-only --pretty=format:"" -- "*.txt"
Documentation/RelNotes/2.8.0.txt

Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.1.txt
Documentation/git.txt
```

That would list all contribution to txt files made by Junio C Hamano.

Comment: Thanks @VonC The command listing few files only. Do this command list files even it is merged in master? I would like to list all the files I edited in master branch which is merged from my feature branch.

Comment: `git merge-base my_feature master`..master