# How to show only filenames by commiter with git log

Tags: git, version-control

Is it able to show only changed File of each Author with git log

Example Output:

```
user1
file1.txt
file3.txt
file2.txt

user2
file1.txt
file4.txt
fil6.txt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get git to tell me all the files one user has modified?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349139/can-i-get-git-to-tell-me-all-the-files-one-user-has-modified)

Comment: sorry, i missed but it is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log --format=%an | sort -u | while read line; do echo $line;git log --author="$line" --pretty='/ %h' --name-only | grep -v ^/ | grep -v ^$ | sort -u;echo ""; done
```