# How can i get file list from a git branch which are committed by me

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, version-control

I am working on project, in which a branch say `feature/test` is used by N number of developers. All developers currently commit their changes and push to same branch.

Now i want to find all files on which i have worked in branch `feature/test`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get git to tell me all the files one user has modified?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349139/can-i-get-git-to-tell-me-all-the-files-one-user-has-modified)

Answer (score 1):

```
git log  --stat --name-only --author="your_name"  --pretty=format:"" --branches=your_branch|sort -u
```

Source - [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6349483/4157479)

Comment: Dude above command giving some extra files which are not related to that branch or not modified by perticular user.

Comment: Try to use --committer instead of --author