# How to do `git grep` only in files I have committed?

Tags: git, search, grep

Is there a way to make `git grep` only match files that I have committed?

The purpose is to grep in the contents of the file, not the log message.

Comment: Define "files that I have committed": Files that no one else ever modified? Files modified anytime by one of your commits? Files where the last commit touching them is by you? Something else?

Comment: Condition as for `git log --committer=<pattern>` does just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to grep in the diff of a commit, you should probably use `git log -G` or `git log -S` :

```
git log -p --author="your name" -G pattern
```

---

Both `-G` and `-S` will look for the pattern in the diff introduced by a commit,
the difference is (`git help log`) :

> To illustrate the difference between `-S<regex> --pickaxe-regex` and `-G<regex>`, consider a commit with the following diff in the
>   same file:
>
> ```
> +    return !regexec(regexp, two->ptr, 1, &regmatch, 0);
> ...
> -    hit = !regexec(regexp, mf2.ptr, 1, &regmatch, 0);
> ```
>
> While `git log -G"regexec\(regexp"` will show this commit, `git log -S"regexec\(regexp" --pickaxe-regex` will not (because the
>   number of occurrences of that string did not change).

When using `-p` in conjunction with `-G` or `-S`, only the files matching the pattern will be displayed.

Comment: The purpose was to grep in the contents of the file, not the log message.  I have update the question to clarify this.

Comment: @EquipDev : that's exactly what `-G` and `-S` do : they grep in the *content* of the commit, not in its message

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware for -G and -S; still learning Git :-)  Great that the git command can do that with options, instead of having to add pipes, since it thereby also works on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

```
author="your name"

git log --pretty="%H" --author="$author" | while read commit_hash; do git show --oneline --name-only $commit_hash | tail -n+2; done | sort | uniq |xargs grep -i "String to grep"
```

OR shorter version:

```
author="your name"
git log --no-merges --author="$author" --name-only --pretty=format:"" | sort -u |xargs grep -i <string>
```

[Orignal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349139/can-i-get-git-to-tell-me-all-the-files-one-user-has-modified) used to get the files from a particular user

Comment: The purpose was to grep in the contents of the file, not the log message.  I have update the question to clarify this.

Comment: @EquipDev this will indeed grep from the contents of the files commited by the author not the log.