# Git log to show a user's modified files sorted by type

Tags: git, git-log

For some reports at work, I have to send files I have modified this month, grouped by type. I've been working on a `git log` command to show the filenames and status, but it would help me if I could get it to sort by file extension as well.
Working from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6349483/1397117) I have gotten to:
`git log --no-merges --author="me" --after={2019-03-31} --name-status --pretty=format:"" | sort -u`

Now I'm stumped on how to sort this list by filename.

This is the current output, but usually with tens of files:

```
M   package.json
M   src/app/spa/components/component1/comp1-tpl.html
M   src/app/spa/components/component1/comp1-component.ts
M   src/app/spa/components/component1/comp1-services.ts
M   src/app/spa/components/component1/comp1-services.spec.ts
A   src/app/spa/components/component2/comp2-tpl.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "filename", if you mean the path:

```
git log --no-merges --author="me" --after={2019-03-31} --name-status --pretty=format:"" | sort -k2
```

If you mean the name without any parent directories:

```
git log --no-merges --author="me" --after={2019-03-31} --name-status --pretty=format:"" | while read type path;do echo "$(basename $path) $type    $path";done | sort -u | cut -f2- -d' '
```

Comment: First one is almost exactly what I needed, but I still get duplicates (from files modified in multiple commits).
If you can just add a `| sort -u` or `| uniq` to the end, I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @VitorM.Barbosa try `sort -u | sort -k2`. If you want a path to occur only once no matter what status it is, use `sort -k2 -u` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have a idea. Add "grep .ext" in the following of command. For the result redirect a output in file. Then do the same thing for other extension. At the end, you obtain the totally files ordered by the extension. Do you understand my idea ? 
For your example report.txt containt a ordered list.

-> **git log --no-merges --author="me" --after={2019-03-31} --name-status --pretty=format:"" | sort -u | grep "\.html" >> report.txt**

-> **git log --no-merges --author="me" --after={2019-03-31} --name-status --pretty=format:"" | sort -u | grep "\.json" >> report.txt**

-> **git log --no-merges --author="me" --after={2019-03-31} --name-status --pretty=format:"" | sort -u | grep "\.ts" >> report.txt**

Comment: Makes sense, this will work fine when I have only a few file extensions, but it will be slower with more.

Answer (score 1):

You could prepend the extension before sorting like this:

```
> git log --no-merges --author="me" --after={2019-03-31} --name-status --pretty=format:"" | sed -r 's|.*(\.[^.]+)$|\1\t&|;' | sort -u
.html   A   src/app/spa/components/component2/comp2-tpl.html
.html   M   src/app/spa/components/component1/comp1-tpl.html
.json   M   package.json
.ts     M   src/app/spa/components/component1/comp1-component.ts
.ts     M   src/app/spa/components/component1/comp1-services.spec.ts
.ts     M   src/app/spa/components/component1/comp1-services.ts
```

Comment: Good, thanks!  
For my fellow Mac users, if you get this error: `sed: illegal option -- r`, it can be solved with `brew install gnu-sed` and then changing the command to use `gsed`.