# Git list all the files I modified in the past

Tags: git

Is it possible to have git print a list of files, with full path from the git root, where my name *appears* in the log?

We have a reasonably sized GIT repository with a sensible directory hierarchy.
I have worked on this code base for 12+ years, so I forget which modules I contributed to.

I don't particularly need the specifics of the changes.
I just need the file names and which directory they live in.

Comment: What if the files move around, are renamed, or deleted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349139/can-i-get-git-to-tell-me-all-the-files-one-user-has-modified

Comment: When you say "name appears in the log", do you mean where your name appears in the commit message or where you are the author of the commit? Or both?

Comment: Personally I don't care that the nature of the change is, as long as my name appears even once in the log. But if you think the answer can be broken up into categories of changes then go right ahead. Could be interesting.

Comment: @mkrieger1 why couldn't I find that question earlier? I did look, honest. Mark mine a dupe.

Comment: I used this Google search: `git find all files changed by author`.

Comment: I entered `git list all files that I modified` into DuckDuckGo. I value my privacy. Which backfired on this occasion.